# Export\Import all rows of tables containing varbinary data to\from a file using sql server

Tags: sql-server, bcp

My table looks like (sql server)

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BinaryData](
     [BinaryDataId] [int] NOT NULL,
     [Data] [varbinary](max) NULL,
     [MediaId] [int] NOT NULL,
     [BinaryDataTypeId] [int] NOT NULL,
     [ContentTypeId] [int] NOT NULL
     )
```

I need to export all rows and columns including varbinary data to a file.
Also, I need to import the file data into the table

I tried bcp but all the examples shows how to export a single column.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you have access to SSIS, then your task is simplified. Export it using SSIS to a flat file format.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately I don't have that option.